# Add random number of buttons to view

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

How can I do the following please?

I have 2 UIViews - lets call them MainNavView and SubNavView. 
MainNavView has a set number (6) of buttons on it.

Lets say the user clicks the 1st button on MainNavView, it will take them to SubNavView, and this view will have e.g. 4 buttons on it.
But if they click the 2nd button on MainNavView, it will take them to SubNavView, but there will only be e.g. 2 buttons on it this time.

So for each button on MainNav, it will have a SubNavView with a different set number of buttons on it. The number of buttons for each "SubNavView" is know.

I am a bit stuck on how to do this. I have all my buttons connected to my pushButton action. Then depending on what button is pressed, I create a number of buttons and add to NSMutableArray.

Then in prepareForSegue, I want to send this array to the SubNavView to populate it with buttons. Am I going in the right direction or not?

Below is what I have in my MainNavView.m at the moment. I used the code in the switch-case to test if I could draw 2 buttons on screen in MainNavView (added the code to viewDidLoad initially) and this worked just fine.

EDIT* 
OK looking at some examples, what I will need to do is get the tag of the button pressed on MainNavView and then do all the SubNav button creating on the viewDidLoad in the SubNavView instead based on the MainNav button tag id? Is this correct? If so, in viewDidLoad of SubNavView, how do I get access to what button was pushed? Not sure on this line in prepareForSegue.

```
[vc setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
```

Updated to code to as follows in MainNavView.m:

```
-(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSubNav" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToSubNav"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SubNavViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Get button tag number
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *) sender tag];

        // Pass any objects to the destination view controller here
        //[vc setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
    }
}

enter code here
```

(Old code below)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SubNavViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize buttons;
@synthesize myButton1, myButton2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    int theTag = ((UIView *) sender).tag;

    switch (theTag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"Getting Here");

            buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            // Button 1
            myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            myButton1.tag = 1;
            // X, y, width, height
            myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, 100.f, 100.f);

            UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
            [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:myButton1];

            // Add targets and actions
            [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(getButtons) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
            myButton1.tag = 0;

            // Button 2
            myButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            myButton2.tag = 1;
            // X, y, width, height
            myButton2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 160, 100.f, 100.f);

            UIImage *buttonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
            [myButton2 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:myButton2];

            // Add targets and actions
            [myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(getButtons) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
             myButton2.tag = 0;

            // Add to array
            [buttons addObject:myButton1];
            [buttons addObject:myButton2];

            break;
        }

        case 2:
            NSLog(@"Where to Stay");
            // Create buttons here 
            break;

        case 3:
            NSLog(@"Where to Eat");
            // Create buttons here 
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } 
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToSubNav"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SubNavViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:buttons];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Why are you creating SubNavView's buttons in MainNavView? I think it'd be better if SubNavView created it's own buttons.

Comment: Yip sorry see EDIT above. Just realised what I had been trying to do.

Comment: First figure out how to add just one button, programmatically.  Then add more, randomly, just repeating the pattern of the first.  You're probably getting led astray by the "random number" requirement and it's clouding your thought processes, so ignore that part to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have managed to get buttons added to the screen programatically and have that working as intended. Maybe the "random number" was not entirely clear. Its not a total random number, I will know the number of buttons per subview, it was more the fact that the buttons would not be the same number for each subview. Thanks again though for the help. It helps breaking the problem down to its simplest components first, I agree

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `property` to your `SubNavView` class that will hold the tag of the button pressed. Then, when you create an instance of `SubNavView` set that property before showing it. You will also need to save the selected tag in an ivar of `MainNavView` so you can set the selected tag in `SubNavView`.

Here is an example:

**SubNavViewController.h**

```
@interface SubNavViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger tagSelected;

// The rest of your class declaration

@end
```

**MainNavViewController.m**

```
@interface MainNavViewController ()

// This is the ivar to save the selected tag
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger tagSelected;

@end

@implementation MainNavViewController ()

// Your class code

-(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    int theTag = ((UIView *) sender).tag;

    // save the tag that was selected for later use
    sefl.tagSelected = theTag; 

    switch (theTag)
    {
        // The rest of your switch here...
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToSubNav"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SubNavViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Tell SubNavView which button was pressed...
        vc.selectedTag = self.selectedTag;

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:buttons];
    }
}

@end
```

After that, when `SubNavView`'s `viewDidLoad` is called you can use an `if-else` clause to create your buttons:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.selectedTag == 1) {

        //Do something...
    } 
    else if (self.selectedTag == 2) {

        //Do something else...
    } 
    // etc...
}
```

Hope this helps!